# Being yotzei kiddush when the host doesn't pass

Tags: shabbat, kiddush

If I am a guest at a big Shabbos dinner at which the host makes kiddush out loud at the head of the table, but does not pass wine from his cup or bottle, what should I do in order to be yotzei the kiddush? Should I:

- Pour my own cup before he starts saying the blessing, say "Amen" in response to his blessing, and then drink from my cup?
- Pour my own cup before he starts saying the blessing, say my own kiddush over my own cup, and then drink from my cup?
- ...Would it be l'chatchila acceptable to pour a cup (from wine on the table) after he has finished saying kiddush and I have said "Amen," and drink from that without making a new blessing?
- When I pour my cup, does it need to contain a full revi'it?
- Does any of this change if I am a single woman?

Comment: This question assumes that one must drink some wine in order to be _yotzei_ which would be a surprise to me.

Comment: Is bullet point 3 a question about being _yotzei_ for _kiddush_ or is it a separate question? If it's the latter, it should probably be split into a different question.

Comment: I realize that some parts of this post are not covered there, but the main question is a dupe. You should ask any separate points that you want clarified separately.

Comment: @DoubleAA I have read all the answers to that question and to the questions it links. It would seem based on that information that any of the options in my bullet points is fine, and that it doesn't have to be a full revi'it unless I am saying my own kiddush. (Additionally, there is the option just to hear it/not to have any wine, although it would be better to have some.) Is that correct? If so, I will close my question because indeed it has been covered.

Comment: @DoubleAA I guess one last question would be: is there a reason to drink wine if it's not from the kos used for bentching? (assuming I'm not saying my own kiddush)

Comment: @SAH, if you wish to ask that "one last question" then I recommend you [edit] this post to ask only it and then it can be reopened (or [ask it separately](/questions/ask)).

Comment: @msh210 I am hesitant to edit my question before someone confirms for me that the answers I have extrapolated from the other questions are indeed answers to mine. Once someone does, I'll overhaul

Comment: @SAH I believe your comment ending with "Is that correct?" is, indeed, all correct, though you definitely should consult with your rabbi for a practical how-to.